# Why GET-request in react-native doesn't work?

Tags: android, reactjs, django, react-native, get

Here is my request code

```
backend() {
    GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", `https://randomday.ru/newValue/?value=${this.state.text}`, true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status !== 200) {
        console.log(`${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`);
      } else {
        let json = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        this.setState({ text: json.msg });
      }
    }.bind(this);
    xhr.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log(e.target.status);
    };
  }
```

It starts on push the button

```
<Pressable onPress={() => {
           this.backend()
}}
```

This works fine when i run the project with debugger in chrome, but normally the request returns "0 error".
If anyrhing, i am accessing my server in django.

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.myreact">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say without more error info, but maybe try calling `xhr.send()` after you've defined the `xhr.onload` and `xhr.onerror` callbacks

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help. In the built-in inspector, in the network section it says: dataSent - undefined, status - 0, timeout - 0, responseURl - undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the server with SSL-certificate. In nginx settings you need to use **fullchain.pem** instead of **cert.pem**.